# Raspberry pi-zero python3.9 from flask_ask import Ask gets moduleError, with a module that I already installed

Tags: raspberry-pi-zero, flask-ask

With my raspberry pi-zero W I tried to install these moduls: Flask, Flask-Ask, Werkzeug (the modul that is missing apperantly)

```
from flask_ask import Ask, statement
```

The error I'm getting:
ModuleNotFoundError : No module name 'werkzeug.contrib'

The fun part is that I installed these moduls with sudo pip commands, and now there is a python3 and a python3.9 folder in my raspberry. I can't remove python3, but when I try to reinstall Flask-Ask it says that it is already there , but in the python3 folder, and the moduls that is says is in the python3.9 are not there if I open the specific folder. I'm totally confused as to what to do. Maybe reinstall the raspberry pi to a 64-bit OS instead of the 32-bit that was installed, because I can't even remember if there was a python3 folder to begin with.